Payload e-commerce works in localhost but not in Vercel deployment
I've just created an e-commerce with the last version of Payload CMS (e-commerce template) and everything runs well on http://localhost:3000
I was able to create an admin user, login in the admin area and seed the database. I can see the data in MongoDB Atlas.
Then I pushed the code to a Github repository and imported it to Vercel (I'm not using Payload Cloud!)
I've just changed the following Enviroment Variables:
# Used to format links and URLs
PAYLOAD_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:3000

to
https://www.exampledomain.com
https://www.exampledomain.com

and did the deploy that was successful.
But strangely when I accessed exampledomina.com, the homepage was still in its original state, telling that I should create an admin user and seed the database although the MongoDB URI in Vercel's .env remains the same.
And when I try to reach https://www.exampledomain.com/admin it gives me a 404 error telling that the page doesn't exist.
If I try https://www.exampledomain.com/admin/login it goes back to the homepage (although the address on the top of the browser stays https://www.exampledomain.com/admin/login.
And if I click on the Login or Create Account links on the Homepage it shows just a blank page.
All logs in Vercel have status 200.

/api/graphql

200
Time
October 12 01:07:05.66 GMT-03:00
Status Code
200
OK
Host
www.exampledomain.com
Request Path
/api/graphql

Request ID
9x9nr-1728706025661-995803c412d8
Request User Agent
node
Level
Info

Environment
production
Branch
main
Cache
MISS
Type
Serverless Function

Function
/_not-found
Location
Washington, D.C., USA (iad1)
Runtime
Node.js 20.x

Execution Duration / Limit
145ms / 10s
Memory Used / Limit
140 MB / 1024 MB

I searched in the Internet for days now, but I was unable to find any working solution. As a matter of fact I couldn't even find a similar problem like mine.
Did I missed something in Vercel's configuration?
EDIT:
Reading the building logs in Vercel I found this:
Error configuring redirects: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
   Creating an optimized production build...

I will investigate and bring the results here soon.
